# Android: Force 480x320 screen resolution

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to bring my game-engine from iphone to android. Everything works except the screen resolution.

My engine supports several screen resolutions. But the games made for do have a fixed resolution. So 480x320 would be perfect to have.

I heard that the following change to AndroidManifest.xml will do it:

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="false"
android:anyDensity="false"/>
```

Does this work on any device? Any  better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Officially, this is what applications are supposed to do:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Personally, this page explains why I intend to stay with iPhone and not move to Android.

Comment: What's so difficult about supporting multiple screen sizes?

Comment: Read that page completely. You're supposed to provide different assets to support the different screen densities, as well. That's a lot of work.

Comment: What about screen compatibility mode (1.5/1.6)?

Comment: I forgot to say. The game-engine is C++. So its hard to change all the sprites and things which come across